# Regex Conversion

Tags: grub2, bash, sed, regex

I'm wanting to make a command to edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the timeout from 10 to 2. Could anyone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sed`, `perl` and other tools for that. Here are two examples for `sed` and `perl`:

---

#### Using `sed`:

Start a dry run

```
sudo sed 's/^GRUB_TIMEOUT=10$/GRUB_TIMEOUT=2/' /etc/default/grub
```

if it's ok, then

```
sudo sed -i 's/^GRUB_TIMEOUT=10$/GRUB_TIMEOUT=2/' /etc/default/grub
```

from man `sed`:

```
   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

          edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

Explanation:

- `^GRUB_TIMEOUT=10$`

  [image: Regular expression visualization]
  <sub>(source: [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/i/mH2dReekra7j2_Uj.png))</sub>

  <sub>[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mH2dReekra7j2_Uj)</sub>

  `^` - assert position at start of the string

  `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` matches the characters `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` literally 
  (case sensitive)

  `$` - assert position at end of the string
- `s` -  s-modifier: single line

---

#### Using `perl` and more generic:

Start a dry run

```
perl -pe 's/^(GRUB_TIMEOUT=)[0-9]+$/${1}2/' /etc/default/grub
```

if it's ok, then

```
sudo perl -pi -e 's/^(GRUB_TIMEOUT=)[0-9]+$/${1}2/' /etc/default/grub
```

- `^(GRUB_TIMEOUT=)[0-9]+$`

  [image: Regular expression visualization]
  <sub>(source: [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/i/yW6xNa-pA5hx3VDW.png))</sub>

  <sub>[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yW6xNa-pA5hx3VDW)</sub>

Comment: So let's say I needed to change ssh=22 > ssh=2020 I would use  's/^(ssh=)[0-9]+/{22}2020/g'

Comment: With perl or sed?

Comment: `perl -pe 's/^(ssh=)[0-9]+$/${1}2020/g' input_file`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic one:

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/^\(GRUB_TIMEOUT=\)[0-9]\+$/\12/' /etc/default/grub
```

Replace `2` (after `\1`) with any value you want to put.

- `s/OLD/NEW/` is the substitution pattern for `sed`.
- `i.bak` will edit the file `/etc/default/grub` in place, keeping the original file backed up as `/etc/default.grub.bak`. If you don't want a backup just use `-i`.
- We have matched the line that starts with `GRUB_TIMEOUT=` (Kept it inside a group so that we can refer to it later) and ends with one or more digits (`[0-9]+`).
- In the replacement section we replaced the digits with the value we want to put, keeping the earlier matched portion (denoted by `\1`) as it is.